# insert in cycle

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, insert, while-loop

I have a script on SQL SERVER:

```
while (@i < 100000)
begin
  insert into TABLE_NAME (id, pid, value)
    values (@i
          , (select top 1 id from TABLE_NAME order by NEWID())
          , 'b')
  set @i += 1;
end;
```

It executes really slow. Is it possible to do the same but faster?
Thanks.

Comment: What are your trying to do?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I'm trying to generate table with hierarchy structure, where pid is parent_id, references to id

Comment: But the question is how to insert many rows in table faster then in my script .)

Comment: So each record parentid is the previous id??

Comment: Each parentId is one of the previous ids

Comment: If each parentId is the one from the previous row, why don't you just store it in a variable and use it afterwards?

Comment: Yes, i change (select top 1 id from TABLE_NAME order by NEWID()) to cast(rand() * @i as int), but it dont very speed up script

Comment: @GordonLinoff at start it is empty, i want to write 100k rows in it :]

Answer (score 1):

Your query is really slow because of the subquery, that has to do a random sort on `table_name` in each iteration.

You can just do this using `rand()`:

```
while (@i < 100000)
begin
  insert into TABLE_NAME (id, pid, value)
    select @i, 
           cast(rand() * @i as int) as pid,
           'b'
  set @i += 1;
end;
```

This will always generate a pid less than id.

If this is slow, you may be slowing things down if your database is in FULL recovery mode, logging all operations.

And, then there is this approach.  Generate the 100,000 numbers, assign a random number to each one and then take that random number modulo original number - 1:

with digits as (
        select 0 as digit union all
        select 1 union all
        select 2 union all
        select 3 union all
        select 4 union all
        select 5 union all
        select 6 union all
        select 7 union all
        select 8 union all
        select 9
       ),
       nums as (
           select (d1.digit*10000+d2.digit*1000+d3.digit*100+d4.digit*10+d5.digit) as val
           from digits d1 cross join
                digits d2 cross join
                digits d3 cross join
                digits d4 cross join
                digits d5
         )
    select val as id,
           (case when val > 1 then seqnum % (val - 1) end) as pid, 'b'
    from (select *,
                 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by newid()) seqnum
          from nums
         ) s

This runs quite fast on my machine.  Without the insert, it finished in a few seconds.

Comment: "Your query is really slow because of the subquery, that has to do a random sort on table_name in each iteration."

Comment: i change (select top 1 id from TABLE_NAME order by NEWID()) to cast(rand() * @i as int), but it dont very speed up script

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)